# Share and comment on an article preview

Tags: comments, preview, share

Is there any evidence how 'share' and 'comment' perform on articles previews on a listing? Most of it also depends on the UI, but in general is there any proof these functionalities are used on that views?
Is a title usually enough to trigger a user's will of sharing/commenting?
Thanks

Comment: By articles do you mean media articles (e.g. newspaper, website, etc) or something more general (a particular item or object)?

Comment: Hi @straya.
I mean news.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing these with you, purely based on the headlines (I didn't read the full articles). Very meta.

https://www.patheos.com/blogs/nosacredcows/2018/09/study-confirms-most-people-share-articles-based-only-on-headlines/

https://muckrack.com/blog/2017/07/19/we-bet-youll-share-this-article

https://www.upworthy.com/comments-didnt-read-the-article

https://medium.com/@emilyrosethorne6/we-need-to-start-reading-past-the-headline-but-not-for-the-reasons-you-think-fc64ec53f77b

https://www.campaignlive.co.uk/article/eight-ten-people-read-headline/1374722

In terms of commenting, I guess you mean general commenting such as between friends or on social networks. Because it is very rare in this day and age to find a media outlet that allows public opinion to be shared on its platform, they have to tightly control the narrative they are pushing after all.